# custom arraylist<mygames> get distinct

Tags: java, android

is there any way to get the distinct values of a custom arraylist?

```
public class mystatistic extends BaseActivity {
    public String objectid;
    public String playerid;
    public String playername;
    public String enemyid;
    public String enemyname;
    public String question;


    public mystatistik(String objectid, String playerid, String playername, String enemyid, String enemyname, String question) {
        this.objectid = objectid;
        this.playerid= playerid;
        this.playername= playername;
        this.enemyid= enemyid;
        this.enemyname= enemyname;
        this.question= question;
    }
```

add to arraylist

```
mystatistic mystatistic2 = new mystatistik(objectid,playerid, playername, enemyid, enemyname,question);
mystatisticslist.add(mystatistic2);
```

now i want to get all unique "enemyid"'s from my arraylist "mystatisticslist". is this possible?
thanks

Comment: @ScaryWombat he has also to override equals. The Set itself is not enough

Comment: HashSet of ids ... asked bazillion times

Comment: pass you list to set and then covert back to list

Comment: A set would not allow for duplicates. If I understand correctly, @markus wants to get all entries with a non-duplicate enemyid - it's not stated that all of them should be unique.

Comment: also making list from class `mystatistic extends BaseActivity` make no sens ... why "data" class extends Activity class? why it has a non-default constructor? you should never call new operator on class that is derived from Activity by yourself

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma This alone won't do anything.

Comment: is it any reason why enemies with same id are in that list in first place?

Comment: yes, i want to get ALL unique enemyid's from the arraylist, ive no idea how to get them ;) thanks

Comment: @user902383 yes. this is a statistic page where i want to display and count all games vs each enemy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to do this using only the ArrayList.
Either implement your own method which can be as simple as:

```
private List<mystatistik> getAllUniqueEnemies(List<mystatistik> list){
    List<mystatistik> uniqueList = new ArrayList<mystatistik>();
    List<String> enemyIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (mystatistik entry : list){
        if (!enemyIds.contains(entry.getEnemyId())){
            enemyIds.add(entry.getEnemyId());
            uniqueList.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
}
```

Or use a `HashMap<String, List<mystatistik>>` where eneyId is the key, and a list of `mystatistik` (having the same enemyId) as value. 
If you want to get a list of unique enemies, simply loop over the keySet of the map, get the value and take the first element of the list.

Hope this is roughly what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks! so i always need a loop? i thought the might be a function ;)

Comment: `enemyIds` can also be a `Set<String>` and your check can look like this: `if (!enemyIds.add(entry.getEnemyId()))`. This tries to add the current id, if it worked, then it returns `true`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Yes you will be needing a loop, as you need to check an element inside of your list's element.
@Tom Nice! Didn't know this. Saves a line of code :P

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class mystatistic {
    public String objectid;
    public String playerid;
    public String playername;
    public String enemyid;
    public String enemyname;
    public String question;


    public mystatistic(String objectid, String playerid, String playername, String enemyid, String enemyname, String question) {
        this.objectid = objectid;
        this.playerid = playerid;
        this.playername = playername;
        this.enemyid = enemyid;
        this.enemyname = enemyname;
        this.question = question;
    }

    public static java.util.List<mystatistic> getUniqueEnemyIdList(java.util.List<mystatistic> entireList) {

        java.util.List<mystatistic> unqiueList = new java.util.ArrayList<mystatistic>();

        for(int i=0;i<entireList.size();i++) {

            boolean isUnique = true;

            mystatistic listItem = entireList.get(i);

            for(int j=0;j<unqiueList.size();j++) {
                if(listItem.enemyid.equals(unqiueList.get(j).enemyid)) {
                    isUnique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(isUnique) {
                unqiueList.add(listItem);
            }
        }

        return unqiueList;

    }
}
```